# Why was the ending to the Arrancar arc so brief?

Tags: bleach

I started watching Bleach probably a month ago and quickly found it to be quite interesting. But there are some things *I just don't get*.

For example Aizen... I thought Aizen was awesome. He commands such awe, attention and fear and you can tell that from the Shinigami's protecting Karakura town.

But I don't get is reason for *being*.

As far as I remember, every villain that Ichigo came across and defeated - at least the fairly important ones had a background story.

To digress Grimmjow, Barragan, No 1 and 3, 5 (+ Neliora) Espada's etc.. had a "beginning".

Disappointingly, Ulquiorra (my favorite Espada - btw) had none.

Kaname had a reason for being. Even Gin - also another disappointment imo - had a beginning, despite its vagueness.

But back to Aizen - from the very beginning he was just someone that had twice the amount of reiatsu when compared to a Captain level.

From what I got he simply wanted more power. To destroy the soul king and in turn destroy 
Soul Society.

But what happens after that? He obviously finds Hollows insignificant, he hates the Shinigami but we don't know why.

I'm not sure if many people feel the same way but there just wasn't enough back story as to why Aizen *is*.

In the end all we got was some speculation from Ichigo - that doesn't really make sense btw - about how Aizen felt lonely because no one matched his power.

So to find an equal Aizen groomed Ichigo's powers, but the funny thing is Aizen, according to Ichigo's speculation in the meantime sought *more* power by subjugating the Hogyouku to his will.

If he had so much power, and he felt lonely simply because he outclassed all others, why not find a way to suppress if not completely get rid of his powers akin to Zaraki's eyepatch?

Ichigo speculates that maybe Aizen let go of his sword willingly, but in Room 46 he doesn't look like someone that gave up his sword "willingly".

The "explanation" that we get from Ichigo sounds rather similar to what the author gave us about Jin Kariya. But there was a reason for Jin's motive and considering his back story the explanation for his defeat does make sense.

But Aizen... I just don't get it.

If anyone can make sense of my question, can you give me a satisfactory answer? :P

Comment: I don't know if you already read it, but try reading the "Official Character Book 3 UNMASKED", it shows a part of Ulquiorra's past. It may clarify a little the beginning of this character for you ^^.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be asking what the title says at all. It seems to be more about Aizen's motivations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the whole thing will be explained in the manga. I haven't caught up yet completely but last I saw

> it looked like stuff's gonna go down with the soul king so I expect they'll explain more regarding that.Also at the start of the current arc they briefly showed Aizen being locked away almost as if they were hinting you should keep him in mind. I think it's gonna go deeper.

Comment: Interesting. I haven't read the manga yet. Sounds promising so I will schedule sometime to see it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Aizen had two conflicting goals. One was to become even more powerful and destroy the Soul King, and the other was to find someone who was his equal. He's a multi-faceted character.**

From *Bleach* episode 310 Ichigo says to Urahara,

> When I battled Aizen, I finally had enough power to feel his sword. And I could tell you with certainty that there was nothing but loneliness in that weapon.

Ichigo states this with **certainty**, so this whole speech doesn't come off as some idle speculation you can dismiss offhandedly. Ichigo goes on to say that Aizen was isolated because of his power and was looking for an equal, but that he probably gave up. Keep in mind that he was pursuing his hollowification research long before Ichigo was around. Naturally, he would have been more focused on the goal he thought he could achieve: gaining more power and destroying the Soul King. When, in the process of his hollowification experiments, he discovered Ichigo's unusual case, he became interested and decided to pursue his other goal at the same time by grooming Ichigo into a powerful entity.

Ichigo also states that there must have been times Aizen must have wanted to go back to being a simple soul reaper. Even so, I very much doubt that trying to get rid of his power would have been something Aizen would have pursued. You have to keep in mind his other personality traits: he's manipulative, driven, calculating, and conceited. His loneliness is something he keeps locked up deep in his heart. He'd definitely rather have someone rise up to his level rather than to weaken himself (it's the same with Zaraki, too).

In episode 309, Aizen briefly talks about the Soul King with Urahara as he's being sealed away.

> **Aizen**: With your great intellect, why don't you take independent action? Why in the world is it that you choose to subjugate yourself to that thing?

Aizen shows a very deep hatred of the Soul King and the current state of the Soul Society. He says only losers talk about the way the world is and winners should talk about the way the world should be. I think this shows his motivation for wanting to kill the Soul King.

I've only read up to volume 68 in the manga, but I've seen that Aizen will continue being in the story, so more of his backstory and motivations may be explained in later volumes.